# x-www-form-urlencoded working in postman but not in fetch react js with Authentication for JWT token using dotnetcore ASP.net

Tags: authentication, .net-core

I am facing the same issue since a week. I have tried lots of things to resolve it :(
Since its as it is, Can anyone help me out for the issue why I am not able to call my API with fetch but able to call it using postman?

Below is my code for further reference, I have enable CORS at server side where I have made my API.
The APIs are build in ASP dotnet core.

Both API and react project is running in my localhost if I try to call that API using postman than its working with same parameter but its not working with fetch,

NOTE: If I set [AllowAnonymous] in my API than it give me response as expected and same as postman.
But I want the functionality which must be authenticated the key passed by client and than return the JWT token to client.

I am tired now please help me out if anyone have solutions for same.

```
  var param={
  grant_type: 'password',
  username: 'username',
  password: 'password'
  };

  var formData = [];
  for (var property in param) {
  var encodedKey = encodeURIComponent(property);
  var encodedValue = encodeURIComponent(param[property]);
  formData.push(encodedKey + "=" + encodedValue);
  }
  formData = formData.join("&");

  let headers2 = new Headers();          
  headers2.append('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8');
  headers2.append('AuthServerKey', 'AUTHENTICATIONKEY');

 fetch(URL, {
   mode:'cors',
   method: 'post',
   withCredentials: true,
   crossdomain: true,
   headers: headers2,
   body: formData
 }).then(function(response) {

alert(response);
if (response.status >= 400) {
throw new Error("Bad response from server");
}
 response.json().then(function(data) {
 console.log(data);
 });
 //console.log(response);
 //return response.json();
 }).catch(err => {
 console.log('caught it!',err);
  })
```

Thanks